# small/tiny and overlap button, toolbox and etc in windbg on windows 10

Tags: windows, winforms, user-interface, windbg, highdpi

I installed windbg on windows 10 (it worked fine on windows 7 for example)
The toolbar is too small, some text boxes are overlapped with other objects.

the text in some places was too small as well and I solved it by changing the font size of windbg, but it didn't solve the toolbox and the text-box issue

I think that maybe this problem is not related to windbg only, and it will reproduced in another applications

Any help would be appreciated.

you can see a screenshot here:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxhak71ruokb01e/windbg.PNG?dl=0]

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/

Comment: you used an old Windbg version for Windows 8.1, get always the [last version from ast Win10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (currently: 10.0.15063.468)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of WinDbg is ancient, I believe this is fixed in newer versions.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg

Comment: Thanks!!! this solved the problem (I had multiple versions of windbg, I thought this is the latest one)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are running with High DPI? WinDbg is probably not fully DPI aware.